# can I get visual studio to open a drag/dropped .sln file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Mostly there in the title. I'd like to be able to drop a .sln file onto a blank VS 2010 surface -- with no solution open -- and have it open the solution. Is there any way to get VS to do this? All I get is the crossed-circle, indicating I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/420374/drag-and-drop-files-on-vs2008-editor-area) in Visual Studio when running Visual Studio in Vista or later.

While the bug is reported for Visual Studio 2008, I believe that it is the same problem for 2010 as well.

Comment: Ack, it's been "Closed (as External)". So they aren't gonna fix it. Sigh.